# Is there a way to change database connection for aasm in ruby in a multi-database setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, aasm

We are connecting to multiple databases. And we are using aasm gem to switch state from `created` to `syncing`. However, while switching states aasm throws an error `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection is closed):`

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your code doing when switching states?

Comment: @JoelBlum in :after callback of the event configuration, we have a notification to slack. While switching states, there's no activity occurring.